# Converting Fasttext vector to word

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, gensim, fasttext

I am having trouble converting a fast FastText vector back to a word.
Here is my python code:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
en_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.en/wiki.en.vec')
vect = en_model.get_vector("turtles")
```

How can I take the vector (especially an arbitrary vector with the proper dimensions) and have it spit out a word?

Comment: `words = ['turtles','flower','hello']`
`vect = {word: en_model.get_vector(i) for i in words}`

i did something similar previously and i decided to place it in a dictionary so that i do not lose the exact word. maybe you could try something similar to this

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `ret_vals = en_model.similar_by_vector(vect)` (see [similar_by_vector](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.similar_by_vector)).  Since `vect` is any arbitrary vector, you'll get back the closest matches.  You can control the number you get back with the param `topn=XX`.  If not supplied, you'll get back the top 10.  The return values are a list of tuples, formatted (str, float) where str is the word and float is the similarity.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for the speedy reply. First stackoverflow post!